# Has anyone successfully solo'd a helicopter with no actual flight experience?

Tags: flight-training, flight-simulator, vtol

Especially at low speed, such as during takeoff, while hovering, and while landing, helicopters are famously difficult (impossible) to control for someone with no experience. Is there a documented instance of any person ever successfully taking off, hovering, and landing a helicopter with no actual flight experience? It must all be in one flight, first time--someone teaching themselves over multiple short flights / hours does not count.  Simulator use is OK and does not count as actual flight experience for the purposes of this question.

Comment: What about the first person to ever fly a helicopter?

Comment: Those guys went step by step over multiple flights. I'm looking for someone who went up for more than just a few seconds on their first ever flight, remained in control, and landed.

Comment: I very much doubt it. [This guy tried and failed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6lZ5R4cvxs)

Comment: I've never flown a helicopter, but I think if it as being like operating a motorcycle, where each limb has specific combinations of things to do in order for smooth operation.

Comment: By 'flight experience' do you mean 'helicopter flight experience'?

Comment: Yes, I mean helicopter flight experience.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, [Eric "Winkle" Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Brown_(pilot)) took delivery of a Sikorsky R-4 and flew it after reading the flight manual and getting a briefing from a USAF Sergeant. He had no experience or training in helicopters. He wrote about it in "Wings of the Weird and Wonderful".

Comment: His story on the linked wikipedia page is outstanding -- well worth the few minutes to read it for anybody with an interest in aviation history from the 1930's-40's-50's era.

Comment: While having no helicopter flying experience, Brown was an experienced fixed wing pilot.

Comment: Brown made several practice attempts before his flight. Great example of a self-taught heli pilot, but doesn't count.